# How to insert a new column to a specific index to a Dask DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, dask

With pandas, I can insert a new column to a specific location like below:

`df_all.insert(loc=10, column="label", value=label_column, allow_duplicates=True)`

How can I add a new column to a specific location with dask? (to a dask dataframe)

Comment: It doesn't say anything about it in the [Dask documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#create-dataframes); 
but this doesn't work then `df_all.insert(10, 'column_label', some_column_value).compute()`? Depending on where you get your `some_column_value` from you might have to call `.compute()` on it as in `df_all.insert(10, 'column_label', some_column_value.compute()).compute()`.

Comment: Dask dataframes do not support insert `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'insert'`

Comment: And that is why I asked this question. "How?" if possible...

Answer (score 0):

Naively, I would add a column

```
df["label"] = label_column
```

And then I would rearrange columns with another getitem call

```
df = df[[..., "label", ...]]
```

There might be a cleaner way to do this, but this should work fine.

Comment: I will try this and give you a feedback. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I neglected this question. I haven't tested this yet but rearrangin based on column names isn't something I am looking for since I will not always know the column names. There is also another workaround for it but as you said: there might be a cleaner way.